# GeoServer WPS python script example does not work without yield

Tags: geoserver, wps

I am using GeoServer 2.5.1, geoserver-2.5.1-wps-plugin and geoserver-2.5.SNAPSHOT-python-plugin.

I want to write a WPS process that calculates and returns some data ( a 2d array) at a point.

I have started with the example here http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/processing/scripting/processcreate.html

The example suggests I should get back features with the interesting data in the properties section i.e.

```
{
  "type":"Feature",
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[
      6,
      3
    ]
  },
  "properties":{
    "distance":6.708203932499369,
    "bearing":63.43494882292201
  },
  "id":"fid--ad4a787_1394a31a374_-7bba"
},
```

however I get back an empty properties i.e.

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,2]},"properties":{},"id":"fid-46aa2cd3_1468a3a8846_-7fee"},
```

I have also tried this using OpenGeoSuite-4.0.2 with exactly the same result.

So am I doing something wrong?

Update...

OK my fault.  I have found what was wrong but I don't understand why.

In my efforts to return some interesting data, not just a geometry, I edited the script so that the run method did not use yield i.e.

```
run((origin, features):

  layer = Layer()
  for f in features.features():
    ...
    layer.add(Feature({'point' : p, , 'distance': d, 'bearing': b})

  return layer
```

This resulted in the empty properties.
I understand that the yield will return an iterable of Features which I think somehow gets translated into a org.geotools.Feature.FeatureCollection.  But I don't understand why the above code doesn't work correctly.

I have also tried returning a list of Features i.e.

```
f = []
  ...
  f.append(Feature({'point' : p, , 'distance': d, 'bearing': b})
return f
```

but this results in the exception

An error occurred while encoding the results of the process
org.python.core.PySingleton cannot be cast to org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection

Comment: I have created the issue for this bug on JIRA
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-6552?jql=project%20%3D%20GEOS

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).